# JQuery sort items by last name

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, html-table

I want to have sorting on the last name and text to be replaced but I am not able to do it. I have tried following.

**HTML**

```
<div id="sort-by-name">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="names">
            <span class="toggle"></span> Betty j. Sean
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="names">
            <span class="toggle"></span> Ali Khan
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="names">
            <span class="toggle"></span> Will Turner
          </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**// Sort names**

```
var items = [];
$('#ByMember table tbody .irwMemberName').each(function () {
    items.push($(this).html());
});
items.sort();
console.log(items);
```

I have also try adding a class to last name word. Then applied above sort function it actually sorts all last names but how I can sort whole by that and replace.

```
$("#sort-by-name table tbody .names").html(function(index, old) {
    return old.replace(/(\b\w+)$/, '<span class="name_identifier">$1</span>');
});
```

Please let me know if I am not clear. Also Ignore any typo's I have modified code here for post.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Could you add some detail or try to explain it a little better?

Comment: I just wanted to implement alphabetical sorting on last name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this. Check fiddle: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/tf1um0tL/)

```
var els = $("#sort-by-name table tbody tr")
.sort(function(a,b){
    var t1 = $(a).find('.names')[0].innerText.split(' ').pop(),
            t2 = $(b).find('.names')[0].innerText.split(' ').pop();

    if(t2 < t1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
      return -1;
    }
})
.each(function() {
  var t = this.innerText.replace(/(\w+)$/, '<span class="name_identifier">$1</span>');
  return $(this).html( t );
});
$('#bodyid').html(els);
```

Comment: Its not working... please verify you fiddle. It should sort on `last name`.

Comment: It perfectly sorts to  Khan, Sean, and Turner vs original Sean, Khan, Turner. I added Willy Baba for your convenience.

Comment: yeah its working fine in chrome I was check in firefox `44.0` its not working there.

Comment: @AamirShahzad Firefox uses the [`textContent` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent), not `innerText`.

Comment: @AamirShahzad I replaced `innerText` with jQuery `html()` function. It now works in Firefox too. Check again - [https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/tf1um0tL/](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/tf1um0tL/)

Answer (score 1):

To add to Nikolay's answer, I've built a version that works both on Firefox and Chrome.

```
var els = $("#sort-by-name table tbody tr")
  .sort(function(a, b) {
    var t1 = $(a).find('.names')[0].textContent.split(' ').pop(),
      t2 = $(b).find('.names')[0].textContent.split(' ').pop();

    if (t2 < t1) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return -1;
    }
  })
  .each(function() {
    debugger;
    var t = this.textContent.trim().replace(/(\w+)$/, '<span class="name_identifier">$1</span>')
    return $(this).html(t);
  });
$('#bodyid').html(els);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tf1um0tL/3/)